# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: newClaimStoreProvider after 2013 to 2013 SP1 CD update

Tags: 2013, dd4t, 2013-sp1, ambient-data-framework

We are trying to upgrade a DD4T site from 2013 to 2013 SP1.  We updated the Tridion dll's, DD4T dll's and all the jars.  This is the stack trace we are getting.  Did we miss a jar?  Does SP1 have a change in the config files?

```
 <JavaException>
 <Type>java/lang/NoSuchMethodError</Type>
 <Message><![CDATA[newClaimStoreProvider]]></Message>
 <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: newClaimStoreProvider
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
  at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.Claimstore.Providers.ClaimStoreProviderFactory.NewClaimStoreProvider(AmbientDataConfig config, String defaultProviderClass)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup()
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Java.Lang.Throwable: <JavaException>
 <Type>java/lang/NoSuchMethodError</Type>
 <Message><![CDATA[newClaimStoreProvider]]></Message>
 <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: newClaimStoreProvider
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
  at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.Claimstore.Providers.ClaimStoreProviderFactory.NewClaimStoreProvider(AmbientDataConfig config, String defaultProviderClass)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup()
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configs have not noticeably changed.  There might be some new elements, but all the legacy ones remain.  It appears you missed the cd_ambient.jar file.  The ClaimStoreProviderFactory is in there:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but cd_ambient.jar is present

Comment: look at the cd_core.log. There should be more info about the error. Probably related to ADF configuration.

Comment: thanks for the responses.  it was a build problem.  I had the jars in ~/bin/lib but the build process was copying old jars over them.

Answer (score 2):

Check you have the Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll in place.  It may be this file is missing or not up to date and possibly leading to the failed class load.